# Put 3 pictures to database after uploading

Tags: php, database, mysqli, upload, insert

PHP upload looks like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "videoCover/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }   
    }

                        include '../connect/con.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
$vidLD = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidLD']);
$vidYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidYear']);
$vidCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidCity']);
$vidZanr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidZanr']);
$vidQuality = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidQuality']);
$vidTranslated = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTranslated']);
$vidMaker = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidMaker']);
$vidRoles = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidRoles']);
$vidTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTime']);
$imgShot1 = PICTURE1;
$imgShot2 = PICTURE2;
$imgShot3 = PICTURE1;

$sql="INSERT INTO videoinformation (id, vidLD, vidYear,  vidCity, vidZanr, vidQuality, vidTranslated, vidTime, vidMaker, vidRoles, imgShot1, imgShot2, imgShot3) VALUES ('$id', '$vidLD', '$vidYear', '$vidCity', '$vidZanr', '$vidQuality', '$vidTranslated', '$vidMaker', '$vidRoles', '$imgShot1', '$imgShot2', '$imgShot3')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}echo "Video Description are added";

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

This is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="../upload/uploadLD.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


 <table style="width:500px, margin-left:50px">  
        <tr><td>Video ID: </td>     
<td><select id="id" name="id">

            <?php

            include '../connect/con.php';

        $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name");

        mysqli_select_db($db_name, $con);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

        $cdquery="SELECT * FROM newsvid";
        $cdresult = mysqli_query($con,$cdquery);

        while ($cdrow=mysqli_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
        $cdTitle=$cdrow["id"];
            echo "<option>
                $cdTitle
            </option>"; } 

            mysqli_close($con);?>

 </select>
</td></tr>


  <tr><td>Video LD</td><td><input name="vidLD"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Year:</td><td><input name="vidYear"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>City:</td><td><input name="vidCity"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Zanr:</td><td><input name="vidZanr"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Quality:</td><td><input name="vidQuality"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Translated:</td><td><input name="vidTranslated"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Time:</td><td><input name="vidTime"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Maker:</td><td><input name="vidMaker"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Roles:</td><td><input name="vidRoles"></td></tr>  
</table>    





  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Question is: what I have to put instead of PICTURES1-2-3 here in uploading script

```
$imgShot1 = PICTURE1;
$imgShot2 = PICTURE2;
$imgShot3 = PICTURE1;
```

to get uploaded files names to insert them after to database????

Updated shoul looks like this???

```
$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "videoCover/".$name_array[$i])){
        echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        $imgShot[$i]=base64_encode(file_get_contents('videoCover/'.$name_array[$i]));
        $sql="INSERT INTO videoinformation '".$imgShot[0]."','".$imgShot[1]."','".$imgShot[2];
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }   
}
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: *Curious:* Why are you using `mysql_` in one piece of code, then switching to `mysqli_` in the other?

Comment: sorry ... forgot to change it ... if this is some how related to question I will change it...

Comment: If it works, no need to change it in your question, I was just curious why.

Comment: Changed it )) any way))

Comment: Why upload your pictures to the database.  When I see people doing this, 99% of the time it is a bad idea. You might consider simply storing filepath information on the pictures in the DB.

Comment: Basically ... what i need is .. to upload the file to the server AND get the path URL storing in database for 3 pictures and with the rest filled in information simultaneously. Like ID City ... bla bla bla.. and the for e.g /upload/cover/1img.jpg , /upload/cover/2img.jpg, /upload/cover/3img.jpg. And I have no idea how to get a path way for all this 3 pictures..... from array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand this correctly (store the image in the database and not the path), you could do something like this:

In your "for if moved" statment:

```
$imgShot[$i]=base64_encode(file_get_contents('videoCover/'.$name_arrray[$i]));
```

this will read the contents of the file, base64 encode it so it is transport ready and house it in your $imgShot variable (now an array).

Then your insert statement would look like this:

```
$sql="insert into [...] '".$imgShot[0]."','".$imgShot[1]."','".$imgShot[2]."' [...]";
```

You can then use the image from the database as the base64_encoded interpretation like:

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$img_data_from_db.'" /`>

or php.net/base64_decode it, write it to a new image name and then use it.

Keep in mind, base64_encode does increase the size required to save the image php.net/base64_encode .

Hope this helps.

EDIT:  also, you would remove/comment out this:

```
$imgShot1 = PICTURE1;
$imgShot2 = PICTURE2;
$imgShot3 = PICTURE1;
```

EDIT 2:
shouldn't have put a query in the comment, here is is ...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO videoinformation (id, vidLD, vidYear, vidCity, vidZanr, vidQuality, vidTranslated, vidTime, vidMaker, vidRoles, imgShot1, imgShot2, imgShot3) VALUES ('$id', '$vidLD', '$vidYear', '$vidCity', '$vidZanr', '$vidQuality', '$vidTranslated', '$vidMaker', '$vidRoles', '".$imgShot[0]."','".$imgShot[1]."','".$imgShot[2]."')";
```

Correct?

```
<?php

include '../connect/con.php';

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){

    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "videoCover/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            $imgShot[$i]=base64_encode(file_get_contents('videoCover/'.$name_array[$i]));
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }   
    }



$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
$vidLD = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidLD']);
$vidYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidYear']);
$vidCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidCity']);
$vidZanr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidZanr']);
$vidQuality = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidQuality']);
$vidTranslated = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTranslated']);
$vidMaker = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidMaker']);
$vidRoles = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidRoles']);
$vidTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTime']);

$sql="INSERT INTO videoinformation (id, vidLD, vidYear, vidCity, vidZanr, vidQuality, vidTranslated, vidTime, vidMaker, vidRoles, imgShot1, imgShot2, imgShot3) VALUES ('$id', '$vidLD', '$vidYear', '$vidCity', '$vidZanr', '$vidQuality', '$vidTranslated', '$vidMaker', '$vidRoles', '".$imgShot[0]."','".$imgShot[1]."','".$imgShot[2]."')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}echo "Video Description are added";

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: move the $sql statement back to where it was, the $imgShot is correct though :)

Comment: in the "for if moved" section, your assigning the contents of the image to the array to store for later when you insert it into your database

Comment: @Denis, looks good.  does it run and store the base64 encoded interpretation of the image in your database now along with the other metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You search for `$_FILES`
http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php

You can get all informations from `$_FILES`-Array

Edit: Test this!

```
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="upload.php" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT NAME="file[]" TYPE="file">
<INPUT NAME="file[]" TYPE="file">
<INPUT NAME="file[]" TYPE="file">
</FORM>

<?php
foreach( $_FILES['file'] as $file ){
    print_r( $file );
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer in regards to the OP's question; it's a comment at best.

Comment: I just confused my self I red so much but still can't get in this current situation what I should put? $imgShot1 = to what???

Comment: @Fred-ii- he can't any put into the upload-form/script to get the realnames. The only way is .. use the regular GLOBAL-``$_FILES`` variable from php!

Comment: OP is already using that. OP wants to know "how". Go over the question/code again very carefully. @raiserle

Comment: Question is: what I have to put instead of PICTURES1-2-3 here in uploading script...
to get uploaded files names to insert them after to database????